# Using Terminal C at Berlin-Schönefeld with checked bags

Tags: airports, berlin, sxf

[Terminal C at SXF](http://www.berlin-airport.de/en/travellers-sxf/at-the-airport/airport-map/index.php#finger_tab4) is reserved for passengers with no checked luggage. If I were to check my luggage in Terminal D, and then exit, and go through security in C (only to re-enter Terminal D airside), what is the worst case scenario?

The main reason I ask is curiosity, although if I were very late for a flight at SXF, the horrendous queues in Terminal D mean this might make the difference between catching a flight or not. I have had family members queue for upwards of half an hour there, which is enough to miss a flight even if making the bag drop deadline.

It should be noted that the only reasons I'd try this would be if I had more than enough time to rectify any issues, or if it was clear I was going to miss my flight otherwise and I'd exhausted all other avenues of action.

Comment: I think the meaning of "no checked luggage" is that you simply can't do anything with checked luggage in Terminal C as there are no counters. It doesn't mean you can't go trough security there because SXF, in a way, simply is one big Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

An email to the airport yielded the following answer:

> Dear *redacted*
>
> Thank you for your enquiry.
>
> We are glad to inform you that you may use any preferred security line
>   (in any terminal) to enter the security area at Schoenefeld Airport.
>
> Further information you may acquire via the following link:
>   http://www.berlin-airport.de/en/travellers-sxf/at-the-airport/security-checks/people-and-hand-luggage/index.php

In other words, passengers who check-in at SXF and find the security queues in their terminal long, are fine to use the security queues elsewhere. There's a live indicator on [the airport website](http://www.berlin-airport.de/en/travellers-sxf/at-the-airport/security-checks/apls/index.php).